# How to create a spring data query that returns only those entities that have a UserRole which contains the passed user object?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to write a spring data jpa query that gives me all dashboard entities that have a UserRole containing the passed (or the current spring security principal) user.

Relevant code:

```
@Entity
public class Dashboard extends BaseModel {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<UserRole> allowedUserRoles;     
}

@Entity    
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String uid;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userRoles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet();
}

@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    private String uuid;

    private String displayName;

    private String email;

    private boolean active = false;
    private boolean superadmin = false;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "dashboards", path = "dashboards")
public interface DashboardRepository extends JpaRepository<Dashboard, Long> {

    @Query("...")
    List<Dashboard> findWithPermission(User user);
}
```

Best,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`MEMBER OF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_collection_member):

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Dashboard d WHERE :user MEMBER OF d.allowedUsers.users")
```

Answer (score 0):

the passed user object must already have an ID, that presumably you found while looking up the username and password, simply use that to find which permissions are assigned to the user

the final cross table should probably be

useridsxroleidxpermission1id
useridsxroleidxpermission2id
etc...

Comment: thanks for your contribution, but i dont need to lookup permissions, i just want to filter dashboards that have a userrole which is assigned to my user